# WCF: How to define a DataContract class for an extreamly simple response? Need to deserialize Text of the root element

Tags: wcf, serialization

I would like to call Sql Azure's REST API to create a SQL Azure server. The method is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715274.aspx
I ran into problem. The response from this method is very simple:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ServerName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlazure/2010/12/">zpc0fbxur0</ServerName>`

How do I define a DataContract class for this response?
If response were something like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServerName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlazure/2010/12/"><Name>zpc0fbxur0</Name></ServerName>`
the following class would work:

`

```
    [DataContract(Namespace=SqlAzureConstants.ManagementNS, Name="ServerName")]
    public class ServerName : IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

`

But I need to specify that property should be mapped to the text of the root element. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContractSerializer` as it's created by default cannot deserialize that XML - but if you use a constructor which sets the `rootName` and `rootNamespace` parameters, it can be done.

Another alternative is to use the `XmlSerializer`, where you can use it directly.

The code below shows both options, and also a WebChannelFactory implementation which uses the XmlSerializer type.

```
public class StackOverflow_6399085
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ServerName", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlazure/2010/12/")]
    public class ServerName
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("ServerName[Name={0}]", this.Name);
        }
    }

    const string XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ServerName xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlazure/2010/12/\">zpc0fbxur0</ServerName>";

    static void RunWithXmlSerializer()
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerName));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));
        ServerName obj = (ServerName)xs.Deserialize(ms);
        Console.WriteLine("Using XML serializer: {0}", obj);
    }

    static void RunWithDataContractSerializer()
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string), "ServerName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlazure/2010/12/");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));
        string name = (string)dcs.ReadObject(ms);
        Console.WriteLine("Using DataContractSerializer (different name): {0}", name);
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlazure/2010/12/")]
    public class MockSqlAzureRestService
    {
        [WebGet]
        public Stream GetServerName()
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
            return ms;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlazure/2010/12/")]
    public interface IServerNameClient
    {
        [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        ServerName GetServerName();
    }

    static void RunWithWCFRestClient()
    {
        // Setting up the mock service
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MockSqlAzureRestService), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();

        WebChannelFactory<IServerNameClient> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IServerNameClient>(new Uri(baseAddress));
        IServerNameClient proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        var name = proxy.GetServerName();
        Console.WriteLine("Using WCF REST client: {0}", name);
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        RunWithXmlSerializer();
        RunWithDataContractSerializer();
        RunWithWCFRestClient();
    }
}
```